# Add value from one row to another row if rows have matching substrings in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with dataframes in pandas with an example of a book distributor.

The warehouse produces .csv files that treat signed and unsigned (by the author) copies of books with the same titles as different rows, eg:

```
TITLE      //                      STOCK

A song of ice and fire     //       5

A song of ice and fire (signed)  //  1
```

However, I want each title to be a single row, but with an extra column for signed stock, eg:

```
TITLE            //                STOCK  //   SIGNED STOCK

A song of ice and fire      //       5       //     1
```

I've successfully read in the CSV to a pandas dataframe and added a blank column called `SIGNED STOCK`, padded with zeros. I've also cleaned the code and got rid of blanks and `NaN`s
However, I don't know how to search through the rows for titles with the substring `(signed)` and then add the stock there to the relevant `SIGNED STOCK` column of the relevant title. Any help much appreciated! :)

```
IBS_combined = pd.read_csv("IBS_21_05_19.csv",usecols=[3,12,21],encoding='latin-1')

IBS_combined.columns= ['Product', 'ISBN','Stock']

IBS_combined['Signed Stock']='0'

IBS_combined.replace(['Product'], np.nan, inplace=True)

IBS_combined.dropna(subset=['Product'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like :

```
signed = []
for row in IBS_combined.iterrows():
    if row['TITLE'].find(your_string) != -1:
        signed.append(row['TITLE'].replace(your_string,''))
```

Then you can loop through signed and add the amounts

```
for item in signed:
    IBS_combined[IBS_combined['TITLE']==item]['SIGNED'] = IBS_combined[IBS_combined['TITLE']==item]['SIGNED'] +1
```

Comment: Thanks for this :)
So would I replace "your_string" with "(signed)"?

For example, two rows in the warehouse data look like:

TITLE // STOCK
And Time Folds // 3

And Time Folds (signed) // 1

Comment: Getting the following error:
     30 signed = []
     31 for row in IBS_combined.iterrows():
---> 32     if row['Product'].find(signed) != -1:
     33         signed.append(row['Product'].replace(signed,''))
     34 for item in signed:
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 0):

You can split the dataframe into two dfs with rows having signed, unsigned only respectively and then merge the result. Below is an example (Assumed *ISBN* is the unique key to identify a book and the same book should not have more than 1 entries for either signed or unsigned stocks):

1. Setup sample data which contain ISBNs with:

   - 1 signed and 1 unsigned entries
   - 1 signed stock entry only
   - 1 unsigned stock entry only

     ```
     str="""ISBN // TITLE // STOCK
     1 // A song of ice and fire // 5
     1 // A song of ice and fire (signed) // 1
     2 // another book // 10
     2 // another book (signed) // 2
     3 // 2nd book // 3
     4 // 3rd book (signed) // 1"""

     df = pd.read_csv(pd.io.common.StringIO(str), sep=' // ', engine='python')
     ```
2. split the dataframe into two dataframes based on the below mask `m`:

   - df_signed: `df[m]`
   - df_unsigned: `df[~m]`

     ```
     m = df.TITLE.str.contains('\(signed\)')
     ```
3. format df_signed (set `ISBN` as index, rename column and remove the substring '(signed)' from TITLE column):

   ```
   df_signed = df[m].set_index('ISBN')\
                    .rename(columns={'STOCK':'SIGNED_STOCK'}) \
                    .replace('\s*\(signed\)', '', regex=True)
   print(df_signed)
   #                       TITLE  SIGNED_STOCK
   #ISBN
   #1     A song of ice and fire             1
   #2               another book             2
   #4                   3rd book             1
   ```
4. setup df_unsigned and use [DataFrame.combine_first()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) to join with df_signed

   ```
   df_new = df[~m].set_index('ISBN') \
                  .combine_first(df_signed) \
                  .fillna(0, downcast='infer') \
                  .reset_index() 
   print(df_new)
   #   ISBN  SIGNED_STOCK  STOCK                   TITLE
   #0     1             1      5  A song of ice and fire
   #1     2             2     10            another book
   #2     3             0      3                2nd book
   #3     4             1      0                3rd book
   ```
5. rearrange the order of columns:

   ```
   cols = ['TITLE', 'ISBN', 'STOCK', 'SIGNED_STOCK']
   df_new = df_new[cols]
   ```